# Insert html into PHP return

Tags: php, html

My PHP is failing me. I'm trying to put a div around an element in a function. Here is the original code:

```
if ($withCurrency) {
    $currency = (isset($GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency)) ? $GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency : '';
    return $currency . ' ' . $lowestPrice;
}
```

I want to put a div around the `$currency`.

I've tried changing this line:

```
return $currency . ' ' . $lowestPrice;
```

to this:

```
return "<div>" . $currency . "</div> " . $lowestPrice;
```

However that actually outputs the div tags as text on the page. Can someone tell me how to add the divs so they render as html?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the entire function:

```
function getTourPrice($tourId, $withCurrency = true) {

    $lowestPrice = false;
    $offers = getTourOffers($tourId);
    // first get price from special offers
    foreach ($offers as $offer) {
        if ((isset($offer->options['special'])) && ((!$lowestPrice) || floatval($offer->options['price']) < $lowestPrice)) {
            $lowestPrice = floatval($offer->options['price']);
        }
    }
    // if special price isn't available then get price from normal offers
    if (!$lowestPrice) {
        foreach ($offers as $offer) {
            if ((!$lowestPrice) || (floatval($offer->options['price']) < $lowestPrice)) {
                $lowestPrice = floatval($offer->options['price']);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$lowestPrice) return false;

    if ($withCurrency) {
        $currency = (isset($GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency)) ? $GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency : '';
        return $currency . ' ' . $lowestPrice;
    } else {
        return $lowestPrice;
    }

}
```

The result of that function is called with the following code:

```
{var $lp = getTourPrice($post->id)}
                {if $lp}<div class="item-price"><span><span><span class="from">From</span>{$lp}</span></span></div>{/if}
```

If I use echo instead of return like this:

```
echo "<div>" . $currency . "</div> " . $lowestPrice;
```

I lose all the html above. I.E. What was the following:

```
<div class="item-price"><span><span><span class="from">From</span>{$lp}</span></span></div>
```

Becomes this:

```
<div>R</div> 56200
```

(where R is $currency and 56200 is $lowestPrice)

Hope that's not painfully convoluted.

Comment: Check for `htmlspecialchars` when outputting

Comment: There is not enough context to understand what’s going wrong. What do you do with the returned value?

Comment: What to you use to output the return value? do you echo it?

Comment: Maybe you echo with `htmlspecialchars`? How do you display the returned value?

Comment: Perhaps you do not set text/html headers but text/plain instead

Comment: Check your output. You probably echo it with htmlspecialchars or something similar.

Comment: If not and you are using Smarty, then change to `{$lp|unescape:"html"}` (or look for unescaping in your tamplate engine)

Comment: I found 'htmlspecialchars' in the functions file and removed it but it still wouldn't work. I tried using '{$lp|unescape:"html"}' but also did not work. Will try looking for unescaping in the template engine. Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This will have something to do with what you are doing with the return

I imagine if you did this:

```
    if ($withCurrency) {
        $currency = 
        (isset($GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency)) ?
        $GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency : 
        '';

        echo "<div>" . $currency . "</div> ";
    }
```

It would work.

Is your code the end of a function?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the :

```
{$lp|escape:false}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply place the div in the $currency variable, so it will be added upon return. I would change this line of code:

```
$currency = (isset($GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency)) ? $GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency : '';
```

to this:

```
$currency = (isset($GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency)) ? '<div>'.$GLOBALS['aitThemeOptions']->directory->currency.'</div>' : '';
```

or another method:

```
$currency = '<div>'.$currency.'</div>';
```

This way you are defining the html in the variable and not in the return. This is not tested, but it is the way I tend to code. :) Hope it helps!

Also one more thing, it is a bit of controversy among programmers, but I also recommend using single quotes when defining html in php.